# How can I secure Spring controller methods for user roles?

Tags: java, security, spring, spring-security, roles

I have `USER`, `ROLE` and `USER_ROLE` tables and a bunch Spring controllers ... is there an Spring annotation I can add to the controller methods that will specify the role(s) a user should have to be able to access it?

I guess it's going to be Spring security? Is that straighforward to wire up to an existing user/role schema?

I'm using Spring 2.5.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security is going to be your easiest way to do it. What you're asking for specifically is [Method Security Expressions](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#d0e5076). You can achieve this by using the following:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public void deleteUser(User user) {
  ...
}
```

It's pretty straightforward to set up Spring Security with a database backend. I'd take a look at the [DAOAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-dao-provider) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention - we're on Spring 2.5.4

Comment: In that case you could probably roll your own annotations and use AOP to perform the lookup for every method you want to secure.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security annotations, as follows:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_1", "ROLE_2"})
public String mySecuredHander() {
   return "foo";
}
```